# ASP.NET Performance %Time in GC Even when application is idle

Tags: asp.net, performance, garbage-collection, ca, apm

I am sorry if the question is too vague. I am not supposed to copy any logs or other information from my work place to public. But here is the question:

In my organization, we have a CA APM team to monitor application performance. One of our applications that is idle (No users as of now as the official release is in next couple of months) is showing the w3wp:%Time in GC as 89 which is higher than the set threshold of 80. From developers perspective the code is not executed but the CA APM tells that this is from our app pool and the server is dedicated for our app alone. Can an idle asp.net application cause a problem like this ? Infrastructure team simply pushes it on to developers and developers are clueless because in their perspective their code is not executed. Any advice, insight in to this topic is highly appreciated.

Comment: The number `%Time in GC` is only updated after a completed GC. No garbage collections means that the number isn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is almost month old but still would like to know the reason. My best 2 guesses are:

- If there's completely no traffic going to website and GC handles are
  still high there might be a scheduled job that's leaking memory.
- If not there might be other apps on same machine that are fighting
  over memory and system forces gc also on your idle app and since your
  app is idle and is gc is being constantly forced the GC% ratio is
  high.